# Bash: if then match on multiple conditions if all are true

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that checks for 3 different variables and matches on true. However I need it to only return true if ALL conditions match. Right now its returning true if only one or 2 conditions match from my list of operators.

```
if [ -z "$VAR3" ] || [ "$VAR1" -ge 10 ] || [ "$VAR2" != "WORKING" ]; then
    echo "app failed "$VAR1" check-ins"
    exit 2

elif [ -n "$VAR3" ] || [ "$VAR1" -le 10 ] || [ "$VAR2" == "WORKING" ]; then
    echo "$VAR3" pid active connection is "$VAR2"
    exit 0
fi
```

Should I just replace the || with && ??

Comment: Have you tried to change `||` to `&&` ....?

Comment: It might be interesting for you to learn about [the `test` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html). (And it's *one* reason you should never add `.` to the `PATH` and name your test-programs `test`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `||` represents the `OR` logical operator, it returns `true` if at least one of the operators is `true`. `&&` represents the `AND` logical operator, it returns `true` if and only if all of the operators are `true`

```
if [ -z "$VAR3" ] && [ "$VAR1" -ge 10 ] && [ "$VAR2" != "WORKING" ]; then
    echo "app failed "$VAR1" check-ins"
    exit 2

elif [ -n "$VAR3" ] && [ "$VAR1" -le 10 ] && [ "$VAR2" == "WORKING" ];    then
    echo "$VAR3" pid active connection is "$VAR2"
    exit 0
fi
```